# Why Django's POST doesn't do anything - not even an error?

Tags: python, django, post, django-forms

I'm doing an assignment for Uni from Python/Django. One of the things I have to do is to create a form where a user can create a new "tournament" on the website. Frontend doesn't matter at all.

I created a model, added some tournaments from the Admin panel and that works fine. But when I try to create a new tournament from the form, and click the sumbit button, I get redirected to my home page (even though nothing specifies in the HTML or views.py that this should happen), I get no error, no data posted and no info back from the command line.

## models.py

```
class Tournament(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    creator = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    players = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="players",)
    created_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    max_players = models.IntegerField(
        null=True, validators=[MinValueValidator(2), MaxValueValidator(64)])
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, db_index=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title} \n {self.creator} \n {self.max_players}"
```

## Forms.py

```
class TournamentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Tournament
        #exclude = ["slug"]
        fields = "__all__"
```

## views.py

```
class TournamentView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        form = TournamentForm()
        print(form.errors)
        return render(request, "tournament_app/new_tournament.html", {
            "form": form
        })

    def post(self, request):
        form = TournamentForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            print(form.errors)
            form.save()
            return redirect("/thank-you")
        print(form.errors)
        return render(request, "tournament_app/new_tournament.html", {
            "form": form
        })
```

## new_tournament.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %} Create New tournament {% endblock title %}

{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}
Create New tournament
{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
<form action="/" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form%}
        <div class="form-control">
            {{field.label_tag}}
            {{field}}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

## base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock title %}</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <p style="text-align:right;">You are logged in as <b>{{user.username}}</b></p>
    {% else %}
        <p style="text-align:right;"><b>Anonymous user</b></p>
    {% endif %}
    <a href="{% url "index-page" %}"><button type = "button"> Main Page </button></a>
    <a href="{% url "login" %}"><button type = "button"> Login </button></a>
    {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see in the views.py I tried to check for at least any errors as suggested on some other post years ago, but I get NO response back.
In the command line i see it as such:

> [22/Jul/2021 13:33:10] "GET /new-tournament HTTP/1.1" 200 1839
> [22/Jul/2021 13:33:19] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 744

I have absolutely no experience in WebDev and no experience in Django. Can you please help me identify problem? If there was at least some error response or anything like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I get redirected to my home page (even though nothing specifies in the HTML or views.py that this should happen)

Oh, but you're specifying that, quite explicitly. :-)

You're POSTing to `/`, not `/new-tournament` (your TournamentView).

```
<form action="/" method="POST">
```

Get rid of the `action` to post to the current URL instead.

```
<form method="POST">
```

---

Additionally, you can simplify your TournamentView to a [`CreateView`](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.1/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/):

```
class TournamentView(CreateView):
    model = Tournament
    template_name = "tournament_app/new_tournament.html"
    success_url = "/thank-you"
```

(yes, that should be all)

Comment: Oh my god, and I spent so many hours on this and somehow didn't see that... Thank you so much! What an embarrassment.